# What UI library can I use to imitate facebook image view overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, overlay

I am developing a web application that displays images. I would like to display my images as an overlay of a whole page like facebook does when you look on your photos in an album. Does anyone know which library to use?

I have looked at the JQuery tools library under overlay :http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html
but I am not sure if the same library can implement an overlay of a complete window. Is it possible?

Thank You,

Comment: lightbox and its many clones...

Comment: @ Šime Vidas: can lightbox be customized to overlay a whole page with scrolling like facebook has?

Comment: You can disable the scrolling of the underlying web-page, but I'm not use if you can use the same scroll-bar for the overlay... at least I'm not sure if the popular lightbox scripts enable that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fancybox.net/ can do galleries with photo navigation (example at bottom of page)